# Why will this csv file not load in R mlogit?

Tags: r, mlogit

SOLVED

This has been blowing up my head all afternoon I simply cannot figure out why I cannot run mlogit on this simple data set

small snip

```
race,horseno,place,win,
1,1,4,0,1,0.7,1,0.33,0.13,0.09,0.72,1
1,2,2,0,0.45,0.78,0.99,0.5,0.22,0.2,0.73,0.98
1,3,1,1,0.42,1,0.99,1,0.18,0.1,0.73,0.76
1,4,3,0,0.19,0.27,0.99,0.17,0.22,0.12,0.73,0.47
```

can be found here, this exact csv doesn't work when I run and this is the error.

```
> x <- mlogit.data(data, choice = "win", shape = "long", id.var = "race", alt.var = "horseno")
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "id1", value = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  replacement has 22 rows, data has 26
```

Honestly if anyone can save me I'd appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the choice situations from your data. Nevertheless, I tried to compare your data with `TravelMode` data in [this tutorial](http://www2.uaem.mx/r-mirror/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf). It seems that `race` in your data is similar to `individual` in `TravelMode` data, which is *the name of the variable that contains the information about the choice situations*. So, I assume that `race` can be assigned to `chid.var`. Here is my trial:

```
dat = read.table(text = "race,horseno,place,win,of,ppf,orf,df,jf,tf,wf,af
1,1,4,0,1,0.7,1,0.33,0.13,0.09,0.72,1
1,2,2,0,0.45,0.78,0.99,0.5,0.22,0.2,0.73,0.98
1,3,1,1,0.42,1,0.99,1,0.18,0.1,0.73,0.76
1,4,3,0,0.19,0.27,0.99,0.17,0.22,0.12,0.73,0.47
2,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,0.31,0.16,0.61,0.81
2,2,4,0,0.24,0.88,1,1,0.09,0.07,0.61,0.92
2,3,1,1,0.16,0.03,1,1,0.57,0.29,0.61,0.98
2,4,5,0,0.21,0.47,1,1,0.25,0.05,0.61,0.92
2,5,8,0,0.01,0.3,1,1,0.19,0,0.64,0.92
2,6,7,0,0.01,0.21,1,1,0.2,0,0.61,1
2,7,3,0,0.1,0.34,1,1,0.16,0.04,0.58,0.79
2,8,11,0,0.06,0.03,1,1,0.21,0.16,0.61,0.92
2,9,10,0,0.03,0.03,1,1,0.19,0.16,0.61,0.92
2,10,9,0,0.01,0.29,1,1,0.09,0.05,0.61,0.77
2,11,6,0,0.01,0.25,1,1,0.09,0.05,0.61,0.77", header = TRUE, sep = ",")

x <- mlogit.data(dat, choice = "win", shape = "long", 
                 chid.var = "race", alt.var = "horseno")
x
# ~~~~~~~
#   first 10 observations out of 15 
# ~~~~~~~
#   race horseno place   win   of  ppf  orf   df   jf   tf   wf   af idx
# 1     1       1     4 FALSE 1.00 0.70 1.00 0.33 0.13 0.09 0.72 1.00 1:1
# 2     1       2     2 FALSE 0.45 0.78 0.99 0.50 0.22 0.20 0.73 0.98 1:2
# 3     1       3     1  TRUE 0.42 1.00 0.99 1.00 0.18 0.10 0.73 0.76 1:3
# 4     1       4     3 FALSE 0.19 0.27 0.99 0.17 0.22 0.12 0.73 0.47 1:4
# 5     2       1     2 FALSE 1.00 1.00 1.00 1.00 0.31 0.16 0.61 0.81 2:1
# 6     2       2     4 FALSE 0.24 0.88 1.00 1.00 0.09 0.07 0.61 0.92 2:2
# 7     2       3     1  TRUE 0.16 0.03 1.00 1.00 0.57 0.29 0.61 0.98 2:3
# 8     2       4     5 FALSE 0.21 0.47 1.00 1.00 0.25 0.05 0.61 0.92 2:4
# 9     2       5     8 FALSE 0.01 0.30 1.00 1.00 0.19 0.00 0.64 0.92 2:5
# 10    2       6     7 FALSE 0.01 0.21 1.00 1.00 0.20 0.00 0.61 1.00 2:6
# 
# ~~~ indexes ~~~~
#   chid alt
# 1     1   1
# 2     1   2
# 3     1   3
# 4     1   4
# 5     2   1
# 6     2   2
# 7     2   3
# 8     2   4
# 9     2   5
# 10    2   6
# indexes:  1, 2
```

Comment: Brilliant that works for me, the scenario is just each race is a different race and the horse no is a individual horse in that race so I think ‘chid’ will work just fine, Thank you

Comment: I'm really glad it helped you. I also experienced several 'stuck' situations when using mlogit several years ago :)

Comment: Haha honestly I planned to spend about one hour on it and it ended up taking five and still didn't figure it out lol. You're a life saver :)